# Android Navigation Drawer Custom Items Not Aligment

Tags: android, xml, alignment, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer with custom items. Each item have a TextView and a Spinner. In the inspector everything looks fine but on runtime nothing is align. Any idea??

[image: In the inspector looks like this.]

On the phone looks like this

[image: Runtime view]

Here is my code

Item Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:title="Busqueda">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_edicion"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/spn_edicion"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_coste"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/spn_coste" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_clase"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/spn_clase" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_fuerza"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/spn_fuerza" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_raza"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/spn_raza"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Here is the code of an item(All items follow same structure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:id="@+id/rl_cost">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Coste:"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_cost"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spn_cost"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try alignment propery set it to left or something

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your navigation view item:

you have to add `android:layout_width="0dp"` for `layout_weight` to work properly.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_cost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_cost"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Coste:"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_cost"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```